# Using the DELETE rest api for branch-permissions in Bitbucket

Tags: rest, api, bitbucket

**

### [CLOSED]

**

I am referencing this [API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.2.2/bitbucket-ref-restriction-rest.html) here. The DELETE call follows this pattern:

```
/rest/branch-permissions/2.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/restrictions/{id}
```

My question is whether I can use this call to modify the users within that restriction ID. For example, if you have a master branch and you want to modify branch permissions for *Changes without a pull request* and say you currently have two users (id:1 and id:2). Can I use this REST call to remove the user with id 2 from this particular restriction ID?

Here's an example GET output that might make it easier to see what I mean to say. In the example json output below I want to remove user with id 2 from under the restriction ID of 102.

```
{
"size": 2,
"limit": 25,
"isLastPage": true,
"values": [
    {
        "id": 100,
        "type": "fast-forward-only",
        "matcher": {
            "id": "refs/heads/master",
            "displayId": "master",
            "type": {
                "id": "BRANCH",
                "name": "Branch"
            },
            "active": true
        },
        "users": [],
        "groups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 101,
        "type": "no-deletes",
        "matcher": {
            "id": "refs/heads/master",
            "displayId": "master",
            "type": {
                "id": "BRANCH",
                "name": "Branch"
            },
            "active": true
        },
        "users": [],
        "groups": []
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "type": "pull-request-only",
        "matcher": {
            "id": "refs/heads/master",
            "displayId": "master",
            "type": {
                "id": "BRANCH",
                "name": "Branch"
            },
            "active": true
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "user1",
                "emailAddress": "...",
                "id": 1,
                "displayName": "...",
                "active": true,
                "slug": "user1",
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "links": {
                    "self": [
                        {
                            "href": "..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "user2",
                "emailAddress": "...",
                "id": 2,
                "displayName": "...",
                "active": true,
                "slug": "...",
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "links": {
                    "self": [
                        {
                            "href": "..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
        ],
        "groups": []
    }
],
"start": 0
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Cinderhaze The workaround I implemented was to take out the whole restriction and then add back the users that were not meant to be deleted.